# What do I find related models using eloquent in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two table rounds and assignments. Its corresponding models are 
 Assignment and Round. Assignment Have relation to round is

```
public function round()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Round::class, 'round_id');
    }
```

assignment have reference key as round_id. I want to get all assignments have the round_id.

```
$assignments = Assignment::find(1)->round()->where('start_date', '<=', $now)
 ->where('end_date', '>=', $now)
 ->where('round_type', '=', 'judge')
 ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `whereHas`

```
$assignments = Assignment::whereHas('round', function($query) use ($round_id, $start_date, $end_date, $round_type){
    $now = Carbon::now();

    $query->where('id', $round_id);
    $query->where('start_date', '<=', $now);
    $query->where('end_date', '>=', $now);
    $query->where('round_type', $round_type);
})->get();
```

This will get you all the assignments of round `round_id` and in the date range `$start_date` and `$end_date`

Comment: `where('start_date', '<=', $now)
 ->where('end_date', '>=', $now)
 ->where('round_type', '=', 'judge')
 ->get()` how to use with the round

Comment: i need round between these dates

Comment: @kittycat Can you please tell me the the table to which these columns are associated?

Comment: rounds table contain  start_date and end_date also round_type column. assignments table contain round_id

Comment: Updated the code. I hope you got the general idea. If you want to filter based on round_type also, add a query below the dates query in the closure.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `where` clause to filter `assignments` by `round_id`.

```php
$round_id = 1;

$assignments = Assignment::where('round_id', $round_id)->get();
```

You can chain multiple `where` clauses.

```php
$assignments = Assignment
                   ::where('round_id', $round_id)
                   ->where('round_type', '=', 'judge')
                   ->get();
```